# How to redraw the datatable with Ajax function

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, datatable, pug

I request data from nodejs server and when I check the google chrome console, it works. But I don't know how to redraw the table with new data.

I think server-side code is okay because I checked the JSON file is returned from server.
My table already has data before with using pug template rendering.

[Client Side Code]

```
function getData() {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Get DATA!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                // contentType: "application/json",
                url: `/${userId}/admin/getData`,
                // data: JSON.stringify(data),
                // dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    Swal.showLoading()
                },
                success: function (redrawData) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(redrawData));
                    $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
                        ajax: JSON.stringify(redrawData),
                        "dataSrc": "dataArray"
                    });
                    // $('#dataTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Get!',
                        'Your file has been deleted.',
                        'success'
                    )
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Failed to save',
                        'If this message is output continuously, please contact to administrator.',
                        'error'
                    )
                }
            });
        }
    })
}
```

[Template PUG Code]

```
                table#dataTable.table.table-bordered(width='100%', cellspacing='0')
                  thead
                    tr
                      th ID
                      th Name
                      th Type
                      th URL
                      //- th explanation
                      th Image
                      th Keyword
                      th Project Start
                      th Porject End
                      th Github URL
                  tbody
                    each data in dataArray
                      tr
                        td
                          a(href=`/${userId}/${data.id}`)=`${data.id}`
                        td= `${data.name}`
                        td= `${data.type}`
                        td
                          a(href=`${data.url}`)=`${data.url}`
                        //- td= `${data.explanation}`
                        td
                          img(src=`${data.imgurl}`)
                        td= `${data.sumlang}`
                        td= `${data.pjdate1}`
                        td= `${data.pjdate2}`
                        td
                          a(href=`${data.githuburl}`)=`${data.githuburl}`
```

Comment: var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();table.draw('page');
put this where you need to redraw.

Comment: use `$('#dataTable').DataTable().ajax.reload()` ...